# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter, authentication

auth_service.dart
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an I/flutter (11774): Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI
This my Code pleaseeeeeeeee help meeee

```
class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = 'http://shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id/api';

  Future<UserModel?> register({
    required String name,
    required String username,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var url = '$baseUrl/register';
    var header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });

    var response = await http.post(
      Uri(),
      headers: header,
      body: body,
    );

    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
      user.token = 'Bearer ' + data['access_token'];

      return user;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Gagal Register');
    }
  }
}
```

Iwant save like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw3bE.jpg)
Please Helpme

Comment: Look at `http.post`. You're not passing the url. I suggest taking a look at https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data and change `http.get` to`http.post`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any url in http.post. Replace

```
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri(),
      headers: header,
      body: body,
    );
```

With

```
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: header,
      body: body,
    );
```

Refer [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data#1-add-the-http-package:%7E:text=permission.INTERNET%22/%3E-,2.%20Sending%20data%20to%20server,-This%20recipe%20covers) documentation for detail information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this to resove this issue

```
// edit this line of your code
====> var header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

// with this
====> var header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'};


// FULL CODE
class CreateGoalModals {
    Future<Add_Goal_Status> create_goal_WB(
    String name,
    String username,
    String email,
   String password,

) async {

final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(
    your_application_base_url,
  ),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },

  body: jsonEncode(
    <String, String>{
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    },
  ),
);


if (response.statusCode == 201) {
print('=========> 201');
  print(response.body);

  
} else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print('==========> 200');
  print(response.body);

  

  // after SUCCESS
  if (success_text == "success") {
    print('=========>  SUCCESSFULLY <===========');

  } else {
    print('========> SUCCESS WORD FROM SERVER IS WRONG <=========');
    
  }
  // throw Exception('SOMETHING WENT WRONG. PLEASE CHECK');
} else {
  print("============> ERROR");
  print(response.body);

  
}
}
}
```